# Capture Text Surrounding Regex Match .NET

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am building an application, and I have a requirement to capture characters before and after matches.  This seems to work okay, except when there are multiple matches within the surrounding capture.

Regex:

```
.{0,10}(?=abc)
```

This should capture up to 10 characters before the string "abc" is found.

The issue comes up if there is a recurrence of the match in the preceding text:

```
"qqqqabcabcqqq"
```

With the above text, I would expect two captures:

```
qqqq (the 4 characters before the first abc occurrence)
qqqqabc (the 7 characters before the second abc occurrence)
```

I am not, however getting these matches.  The only match I get is:

```
qqqqabc
```

I am certain that I am missing something, but I am not sure what. I believe that my regex is somehow being too greedy, and so it is overlooking the first match in favor of the larger, second one. Here is what I need:

I need a regex that:

**1.** Is for .NET

**2.** Looks within a string for X characters before an exact match on string S.

**3.** Includes any secondary match on S (call S') that is found within X characters before S

**4.** does not care in the slightest what these characters are.

I assure you, I tried looking for similar answers but I wasn't able to find anything that directly answers this question (which has been plaguing me for two days.  Yes, I have to use regular expression).  As for Regex flavor, I am working in .NET.

Thank you so much for any help.

Comment: See [this demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28.%7b0%2c10%7d%3f%29abc&i=qqqqabcabcqqq): whole match is `qqqqabc` and Group 1 is `qqqq`.

Comment: I'll look at this immediately.  Thanks very much.  I don't think I can mark your comment as the answer though :)

Comment: I do not think it is a solution since what you ask does not look like a regular regex task.

Comment: This works nearly perfectly, but is there any chance we can have it **not** capture the "abc" at the end of the string, and only any abc that occurs within the preceding characters? i.e. **qqqq[abc *not captured*]** and **qqqqabc[abc *not captured*]**

Comment: I do not quite get it what you need. [This approach](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=.%7b0%2c10%7d%3f%28%3f%3d%28abc%29%29&i=qqqqabcabcqqq) means you need to get `Match.Value+Match.Groups[1].Value` and `Match.Groups[1].Value`

Comment: Wiktor - I am sorry for the confusion.  I can only provide one regex to a function that is going to go search the text of a PDF and get matches.

This means I need to pass it a regex that can work somewhat recursively.  I need it to be go across a string and get them as exact matches.

I do not have the ability to look at the Match.Groups as the actual regex items used behind the scenes are removed to me. It has to know to look for any 10 characters before any incident of "abc", whether or not other occurrences of "abc" are in those 10 characters.

Comment: Good, so you are stuck here - there is no regex solution for this.

Comment: Final note: again, it should not capture the abc at the end of those 10 characters.  if there is an abc within the 10 preceding characters, it should get it, but not the one following those 10 wanted characters.

Comment: Got it.  I will look for some other method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is:

```
(?<=(?<CharsBefore>.{0,10}))(?=abc)
```

Took me a while to remember that .NET allows positive lookbehinds with variability.

[Regex test](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%28%3f%3cCharsBefore%3e.%7b0%2c10%7d%29%29%28%3f%3dabc%29&i=qqqqabcabcqqq)

[Demo in C#](http://rextester.com/BLHZII53156)

I changed the way your initial version worked a bit.

Hope it helps!

PS: I've named the group, but you are obviously free to keep it nameless and work with numbered groups if you want a less cluttered regex, like so:

```
(?<=(.{0,10}))(?=abc)
```

Comment: Thanks very much.  We have already devised a workaround but I will bookmark this so that when it is inevitable necessary to return to this approach, we will have this at hand.